# VS Code/Flutter/Android - Keystore file not set for signing config release

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code, apk

I followed those steps to build apk on VS Code: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

But I always get:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      36,0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I've already tried to create my keys on build.gradle like this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

and like this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

but I've got the same error to build apk.
The official documentation seems to be wrong.
How to create apk on VS Code?

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same error. I think the docs for [editing app/build.gradle](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle) are a bit confusing.

Here is how I solved it. Note the duplicate buildTypes block.

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

Here is my full app/build.gradle (remember to change the applicationId).

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "!!!YOUR APP ID HERE!!!"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: I had a different problem: Google Play did not accept my bundle because it was signed with debug key. I used your answer and I even removed the debug build type. Only then I got the real build error about not finding my key file. If the debug build type is there it is used as a fallback so the errors are being swallowed during build. I corrected the path and then I could sign my bundle properly for Google Play upload. Thank you :) PS: I do not even have Android Studio installed ;-)

Comment: I added duplicate buildTypes, and it worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Android Studio. I did it. VS Code seems to launch a framework like Flutter. Maybe that problem is a kind of test. A patience test.

Comment: No, that is not necessary. See my comment at the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

FYI

Duplicate buildTypes block is not true approach. In this way, you override buildTypes. Although your error seems to be fixed, you are not actually signing the APK.